# Laravel-mix does not see the connected picture in <img src=""> in vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

Component Vue:

```
<template>
  <img src="../../images/logo-icon.svg">
```

Path: /resources/js/components/header.vue

Images: 
Path: /resources/assets/images/logo-icon.svg

Log error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTKLY.jpg)

Comment: try `<img src="../../assets/images/logo-icon.svg">` i see that you're missing `assets`

Comment: Tnx you!!!!!! Your decision helped me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

```
<template>
  <img :src="../../images/logo-icon.svg">
```

or

```
<template>
  <img v-bind:src="../../images/logo-icon.svg">
```

Comment: Boussadjra Brahim Prompted the correct solution! 
Tnx y!